# Optimize complicated SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Apologies if this obvious, but I'm not great at SQL. I have several tables that all need to be joined, but one of the columns can be null.

I have this query:

```
select orders.ordnum, orders.tstamp, orders.sku, code, redeemed_order_num, null as redeemed_date, null as fullname
from customer_subscriptions orders
join bulk_codes codes
    on codes.bulk_order_id = orders.subscription_id
where (orders.sku="bulk-box" or orders.sku="bulk-book") and redeemed_order_num is null
union
select orders.ordnum, orders.tstamp, orders.sku, code, redeemed_order_num, redeemed_orders.date redeemed_date, customers.fullname
from customer_subscriptions orders
join bulk_codes codes
    on codes.bulk_order_id = orders.subscription_id
join customer_subscriptions redeemed_orders
    on codes.redeemed_order_num = redeemed_orders.ordnum
join customers
    on customers.cid = redeemed_orders.cid
where (orders.sku="bulk-box" or orders.sku="bulk-book")
```

The top select returns the top 9 rows and the bottom one returns one row.

Results: 
[image: Screenshot of results]

Is there any way to optimize?

The full schema is here: https://pastebin.com/FXGLetcV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need `left join`:

```
SELECT orders.ordnum, orders.tstamp, orders.sku, code,
       redeemed_order_num, redeemed_orders.date redeemed_date, customers.fullname
FROM customer_subscriptions orders JOIN
     bulk_codes codes
     ON codes.bulk_order_id = orders.subscription_id LEFT JOIN
     customer_subscriptions redeemed_orders
     ON codes.redeemed_order_num = redeemed_orders.ordnum LEFT JOIN
     customers
     ON customers.cid = redeemed_orders.cid
WHERE orders.sku IN ('bulk-box', 'bulk-book')
```

Comment: oh sweet! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Below would be the query.

```
         Select orders.ordnum, orders.tstamp, orders.sku, code, redeemed_order_num, null as redeemed_date, null as fullname
           From customer_subscriptions orders
     Inner join bulk_codes codes 
             On codes.bulk_order_id = orders.subscription_id 
            And redeemed_order_num is null -- comment
Left outer join bulk_codes codes 
             On codes.bulk_order_id = orders.subscription_id
left outer join customer_subscriptions redeemed_orders 
             On COALESCE(codes.redeemed_order_num, 111111) = redeemed_orders.ordnum
left outer join customers 
             On customers.cid = redeemed_orders.cid
          where orders.sku='bulk-box' 
             Or orders.sku='bulk-book'
```

Inthe query given by you, first select would join only redeemed_order_num with null value and in second select there is join on redeemed_order_num, use coalesce or IFNULL function to replace the null value at in join condition